# how to import a .csv or excel file contents into a table in ORACLE 11G

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

i have excel file with me.and i want to create a table with the structure in the excel file in ORACLE 11G. please help me which command is used to do this possible? 
Except SQL Developer Option.

Comment: save your EXCEL file as CSV then use the LOAD command in SQLcl

Comment: sorry, didn't see you wanted to create the table too - there is no 'command' to do this...unless you want to use the SQLDev GUI, which you don't...for reasons?

Comment: you can user SQL LOADER if you save your file as CSV

Comment: Why "except SQL Developer option"? That is the **best** option and it's free, so why are you averse to it? Other than that, export from Excel to a CSV file, and import the CSV file to Oracle with SQL Loader. You will spend more time learning that process than downloading SQL Developer and learning how to use it for this task.

Comment: lol - and @thatjeffsmith is here to help you along the way. Jeff is the god / guru / top expert on SQL Developer, take advantage of that!

Comment: sir i am a beginner in SQL and i don't know how to use SQL developer and SQL LOADER too. that's why i mentioned like that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your test.csv is as follows

1   ahmad   20000

2   ahmad   20000

3   ahmad   20000

4   ahmad   20000

5   ahmad   20000

6   basit   20000

7   basit   20000

8   basit   20000

Create a cotrolfile.txt in any oracle directory and put parameters you want to have as follows in controlfile

load Data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
infile 'path_of_csv_file\test.csv'
Truncate
into table csvload_table
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(Coloumn1,Coloumn2,Coloumn3)

Finally invoke sqlldr from cmd with parameters as follows

> sqlldr username/password control=path_of_controlfile.txt log=path_of_log_file bad=path_of_bad_records discard=path_of_discarded_records_file